# Generate non repetitive combinations from a list of numbers using python

Tags: python

I have the below list of numbers. I would like to generate all non-repetitive combinations of these numbers in length of 9 numbers using Python.

```
[1,2,3,4,5,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,19,21,23,24,25,26,27,28,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,40,41]
```

I tried the below code but it is like running forever and I know that generating combinations of these numbers would put a load on the system but I am not able to get my head around on this and I am very new to Python.

Could anyone please help? This is a task for my training.

```
from itertools import permutations 
perm = permutations([1,2,3,4,5,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,19,21,23,24,25,26,27,28,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,40,41], 9) for i in list(perm): 
    print (i)
```

Comment: You need to indent your sample code so that it's readable. It appears all as one line. I'm not sure I totally understand the goal, but it might be more than your computer can handle: https://gizmodo.com/there-are-more-ways-to-arrange-a-deck-of-cards-than-ato-1553612843

Comment: I see your update... yeah, that's age-of-the-universe stuff. You're dealing with unimaginably huge numbers.

Comment: also, if that's literally your code, it's not valid python syntax. Maybe a missing newline?

Comment: You talk about "combinations", but code for "permutations". They're not the same thing, and since working with all the combinations is actually feasible I think that might be what's intended.

Answer (score 2):

You're calculating permutations instead of combinations.

The sets of `[41, 39, 32]` and `[39, 41, 32]` do not represent different combinations (because they are made up of the same numbers) but they do represent different permutations (because the order is different).

If you use `combinations` instead of `permutations` your code will work.

```
 from itertools import combinations
 x = [1, 2,4] # your list of numbers
 comb_list = [i for i in combinations(x,9)]
```

Also major edit/deletion thanks to @DSM for pointing out my math was wrong. I also had got confused between permutations and combinations and had calculated the size based on a permutation basis! Woops.

Comment: I don't think this is right.  There are 28048800 = 32! / 9! / (32-9)! combinations of 9 elements of a 32-element list.  This can be verified by simply running `sum(1 for x in combinations(x, 9))`, which only takes a few seconds to complete.

Comment: Curious. The code doesn't lie. Why is it a 32 element list and not a 41 element list?

Comment: Well, the OP skips lots of numbers (6 is missing, for example).

Comment: Ahh I didn't check that. I just saw 1 and 41 and assumed. Haha. I've edited my answer. Given you really were the one who answered this if you write an answer I'll delete mine.